# Declaration of Relays

Tags: relay

can somebody help me to clarify the declarations of Relays?

Contact: 250 VAC/28 VDC 10 A RES; 250 VAC 7 A GEN

It's an old [OMRON MK2P-I relay](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/307/MK-I-S_Datasheet-1189591.pdf). AC220V Coil DPDT 8 Pin

Thank you!

Comment: Which part needs clarifying?

Comment: 250 VAC/28 VDC 10 A RES; 250 VAC 7 A GEN

Comment: @ipving In which way you need that clarified? We don't know what to answer so you can reach clarity on this. What do you mean by relay declarations?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a datasheet link (not an ad page). You will find all the explanations in there.

Comment: What was a repeat of what you stated in your question. Which part do you understand? What do you need the relay to do?

Comment: @ipving - Hi, You posted an answer to say thank you. Although that's appreciated, Stack Exchange has different rules from typical forums (please see the [tour] & [help]). An *answer* cannot be used in that way, so it was deleted, sorry. Please see the article in the [help] called: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers)" & follow that guidance. If your question has been solved, consider upvoting useful answers & [áccepting](/help/accepted-answer) your choice of best answer. Or if you need clarification on an answer, you can comment below it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> Contact: 250 VAC/28 VDC 10 A RES; 250 VAC 7 A GEN

The contacts are rated at 250 V AC carrying or breaking 10 A when powering a resistive load.

The contacts are also rated at 28 V DC carrying or breaking 10 A when powering a resistive load.

The contacts are rated at 250 V AC carrying or breaking 7 A when powering a general load, that is an inductive or capacitive load. The contacts are not rated for DC use into a general load.

> It's a MK2P-I AC220V Coil DPDT 8 Pin

It has a coil rated for connection to a 220 V AC supply.

The DPDT means Double Pole Double Throw, that is, 2 separate sets of changeover contacts, though I would have expected to find this on the 'contacts' specification line.

8 Pin means the relay package has 8 pins.

The -I suffix on the OMRON MK2P-I part number means there is a Mechanical indicator to to easily check the contacts status. Thanks to
Chester Gillon in comments.

Comment: While it wasn't part of the question, the ``-I`` suffix on the OMRON MK2P-I part number means there is a _Mechanical indicator_  to ``to easily check the contacts status``.